# Rails 3 Resource routing for join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a many-to-many relationship between users and teams (as a has_many :through), and I'm trying to setup a "team members" join model as a resource in the routes.

In my layouts I've setup a "team context form" that sets a session variable for the `current_team`, and I want the route for the team_members resources to be defined as `/team_members/:user_id/show`.  Is there any way to do this with the `resources :team_members` in routes.rb?

I've tried using `:path_names => {:action => "\some\url"}`, however for actions that require an :id the router appends the route to be something like `"\:id\some\url"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:
If you want to be able to edit the team membership, you could have

```
resources :users do
    resources :team_members
end
```

and then, to edit the membership => `/users/:user_id/team_members/:id/edit`

And then you can do whatever you want in the team_members_controller.

Or as numbers1311407 said, just `resources :team_members` and you'll have all the rest routes to work with the team memberships.

---

Really don't want the standard `/teams/:team_id/users/:id` ?

If you really want `/team_members/:user_id/show`
You could just do

```
get "/team_members/:id/show" => "users#show"
```

But I dont think it's a good idea.

Comment: "users#show" and "users#edit" are actually different from the route and view that I actually want.  I want to be able to edit and show based on team context which user is in the team, and be able to change their permission status as a member of that team.  Since permissions are defined as a part of the `team_member` model, I want to essentially be able to change that one string as an admin of the `current_team`;  I really haven't found a way of doing this other than setting up the routes individually as part of a namespace.

Comment: This reinforces the argument that team_member (the membership) should probably be treated as its own distinct resource and referenced by id, which eliminates all route complications.  It would also allow you to singly nest membership resources under both users and teams.

/memberships/:id, 
/users/:user_id/memberships/:id, 
/teams/:team_id/memberships/:id

Comment: It is by default, right? If he set up a join model, it automatically has an id. edit: sorry, didnt see his comment on your post :)

Answer (score 0):

if the relationship is many-to-many then the route you're looking to write doesn't reference the team, unless this show page is intended to show all teams a user belongs to?

This would work out of the box if you assigned an ID to the join model and simply used its natural GET route, e.g. /team_memberships/:id

Edit: sorry I didn't read the 2nd paragraph carefully, if you are storing the team in the session you could (as suggested by someone else) set up team_members as a singleton resource and pull the team from the session when getting the member.

If it works in the app, though, considering team_membership as its own resource is probably more naturally RESTful.

Comment: I had apparently set the `id => false` in the migration as previously I was going for a habtm.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if what you're looking for is:

```
resource :team_members do
  resources :users
end
```

The "resource" command creates a route where team takes no :id and would allow you to look up the team using your current_team session variable.

You'd get these path in your app:

```
/team_members            #  team_members#show
/team_members/users      #  users#index
/team_members/users/:id  #  users#show
```

In each case you're responsible for looking up current_team.