# path helper for join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have already read the related question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013658/rails-3-resource-routing-for-join-models

I'm wondering how I can have a nice helper which takes an instance of a join model and returns a 'nested' path.

Ex. Many `users` have many `projects`, so there's a `projects_users` join.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

`projects_users_path(ProjectUser.first)`

and get:

`/projects/2/users/3`

instead of:

`/projectsusers/1`

Is there some routes magic I can do with this, or should I just make my own helper method?

Answer (score 0):

check the nested resources section on the rails routing guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

there are some examples for what you want

Comment: Yes, that's what I have defined already, so I can do user_project_path(user,project), but is there something that allows me to do user_project_path(userproject). I know it's easy to do userproject.user, userproject.project, but I thought there might be something even simpler.